# Querying elastic search with linq using NEST

Tags: c#, linq, elasticsearch, nest

Is there any way to query Elasticsearch with NEST client using linq or lambda expressions.

I Want to do somthing like this :

```
client.Search<MyClass>(s => s.MyProperty.Contains("value") &&
                            (s.MySecondProperty == 123 ||
                             s.ThirdProperty > 12)) ;
```

Or

```
var query = from m in MyContext.MyClass
            where ...
            select m
```

I read a little about [ElasticLinq](https://github.com/CenturyLinkCloud/ElasticLINQ) but it seems that it is no more active. the last nuget package were published on october 2015

What i want to do is to create a method that get an Expression as parameter from the caller and search on elastic with it. the caller should not depend on ES or NEST API

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**In short, no.**

The longer answer is, **[ElasticLINQ](https://github.com/CenturyLinkCloud/ElasticLINQ)** is the closest to a LINQ provider that I'm aware of but does not expose all of the capabilities of the Elasticsearch API.

Whilst there is *some* overlap between `LINQ`, `IQueryable<T>` et. al, and the search capabilities exposed by the Elasticsearch query DSL and REST API, there are many queries that cannot be easily expressed with LINQ e.g. what would a [completion suggester query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html#querying) look like, or a [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html#score-functions) or a [moving average aggregation using Holt-Winters](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-movavg-aggregation.html#_holt_winters)?

You would need to extend the methods available in LINQ and write a *non-trivial* query provider, all for the desire to fit a well defined query DSL into the LINQ paradigm.

Personally, I would be inclined to embrace the query DSL and REST API and look to transform your Expression into something that you can send with NEST, Elasticsearch.Net or `HttpClient`. The caller still doesn't need to know how the request is made.

If you do end up writing a LINQ query provider, I'd be very interested :)

Answer (score 4):

The exact query you write there today works just great in ElasticLINQ.

The project is still alive - just sometimes there is no reason for a new release.  There was a point release today to fix a corner case in generating Queries (not filters) using OR's nested within an AND.

Comment: any ETA for supporting v5.x?

Comment: My job no longer involves .NET or Elasticsearch so I'm not sure there will be any movement without help.

Answer (score 0):

I am currently working on the LINQ query provider library to generate NEST method calls. If someone is interested - here is the link to the GitHub repository - https://github.com/VladislavRybnikov/NEST.Linq

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).